# Rails conditions like and gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my rails app i need to search for some data, but for example if in db i have

> clean filters

but in post-data i have

> clean filter

i didn't get what i need, so i need analog of sql %like%, i done this, but how to remove space from data, which is getted from mysql?. Now my code looks like this

```
prlist = PriceList.find(:first, :conditions => ['id like ? and brand like ?', @search.map(&:price_list_id), "%"+supplier+"%"], :order => 'price asc')
```

but i need something like this: 
`prlist = PriceList.find(:first, :conditions => ['id like ? and brand.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '') like ?', @search.map(&:price_list_id), "%"+supplier+"%"], :order => 'price asc'`)

So if simple: how, when fetching data, modify in "ram" sql data?

Comment: Have a look at some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027276/help-with-rails-active-record-querying-like-clause

Comment: @mccannf sorry, i'v pasted old version of question. UPD!

Comment: Are you trying to remove leading & trailing whitespace? if so, then try: `prlist = PriceList.find(:first, :conditions => ['id like ? and trim(brand) like ?', @search.map(&:price_list_id), "%"+supplier+"%"], :order => 'price asc')`