# Ruby on Rails / SQL Query with

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I the following models

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, address, ........

     has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :company_id, .............

    belongs_to :company

end
```

I have a string q and would like to select all the employees whos firstname lastname or company.name are like q, something along the line of this query non working query

```
Employee.where("firstname like ? or lastname like ? or company.name like ?", q,q,q)
```

What is the best way to achieve this with rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Employee.joins(:company).where("employees.firstname like ? or employees.lastname like ? or companies.name like ?", '%q%', '%q%', '%q%')
```

Answer (score 0):

[as mentioned in this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027474/690866), the way to go here is by using a search gem rather than an SQL.

the leading candidate is [Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/searching.html).

another useful answer from the same thread would be:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037835/690866
there he shows what you wanted to achieve, if i understand correctly..

hope it helps.